# How to set external dependency on module in Intel Visual Fortran?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, module, dependencies, fortran

I am attempting to recreate a set of Fortran projects using Intel Visual Fortran (Parallel Studio XE 2013) with MS Visual Studio 2010. The projects had formerly been built using Compaq Visual Fortran 6.6, where they were all part of a single workspace. There are seven projects in the VS solution (what had been the workspace in CVF), of which three are static libraries and the other four are console applications that depend on the static libraries.

In addition, I have one Fortran module in a single file, in which all the type definitions reside, and which is included by means of the USE statement in each of the source files. In CVF this was included in the workspace as an "External Dependency", but MS VS 2010 does not seem to have the same property for its "solution". (?)

So here's my question: How do I add to the VS solution a .F90 source file that defines a module MODULENAME in such a way that when other source files call USE MODULENAME, the compiler will pull in the module MODULENAME defined in that file. I'll put it wherever MS VS wants me to put it, but I haven't figured out how to tell it where to look.

ANSWER: Thanks to everyone who answered down below. Based on those responses, I created a new static library project that contained the single source file that defines the module in question. I then set dependencies on this project for every other project that had any source files with the `USE MYMODULENAME` statement in them. Some of them might not have needed this dependency, if they already depended on other projects that depend on this module; I'm not sure about that. It doesn't seem to hurt to have the redundant dependencies; I assume that the IDE resolves this correctly and doesn't compile the module more than once.

For anyone who is as new to this as I am:

- To add the module as a project, I right-clicked the solution and selected "Add New Project". In the dialog that popped up, I selected "Static Library" as the type.
- To set the dependencies, I right-clicked the solution, selected "Properties" (there's also a button on the Solution Explorer toolbar) and went to the Dependencies panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either:

- Create a separate static library project for the single module that has just the single file, and then make projects that require that module/file depend on that static library project (one of the existing static library projects may already be a suitable container for this).

OR

- Simply add the single file to each project that uses the module defined by the file.

Which is best mostly depends on what you think is best.

Comment: Thanks! This was the best solution for me. In my case it made the most sense to put the single module into its own static library project and then to set the dependencies appropriately for the other projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in [Intel Fortran documentation](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/stdxe/2013/composerxe/compiler/fortran-mac/GUID-5D356F1E-8C56-49D7-8BA6-438E91F2C73C.htm):

> use the -I (Linux OS) or /I (Windows OS) option to specify the path to search and locate the definedmod.mod file

So you need to compile your MODULE and accordingly set include directories in other projects Configuration Properties->Fortran->General->Additional Include Directories

Comment: I would understand all that if I were just doing all this on a command line, but how do I do this in the MS VS IDE? Do I have to make the module file part of a "project" in order to compile it? Should it be its own project? I don't see a project type for "Fortran Module". Shouldn't VS know to compile the module first, once I've told it that the other files depend on it? Sorry for all the questions, but sometimes it seems like life was easier at the command prompt - all the options and properties set through the IDE baffle me.

Comment: It is fine to add the file with MODULE to any existing project. The module will be compiled before its usage within this project. But you have to add "dependencies" to this project to other projects. This is done by solution's properties->dependencies.

Comment: Using a static library project for the module(s) is the way to go. It used to be that you had to both set up a project dependency on the library and modify the Include directories, but the Include directory change is now implicit with a project dependency. Make sure that you set the Libraries > Use Runtime Libraries setting the same in all the projects.